# Good books on Calculus and Geometry

Tags: calculus, geometry, soft-question, self-learning

I have a high-school background in both Calculus and Geometry, and I am looking for some good books on the topics, suitable for self learning. Preferably, books that provide a broad view on the subjects.
Thanks.

Comment: Spivak is the standard reccomended calc/analysis text

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Do you want a rigorous treatment of calculus and geometry? Do you want a treatment which is intuitive/application focused?

Comment: My goal is to discover what intresting developments can be made. I am generaly more into the intuitive and applicative treatments.

Comment: You might wanna try standard college calculus text, such as [James Steward's Calculus](https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Early-Transcendentals-James-Stewart/dp/0495011665)